# How to modify the image of an legend entry

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={size=640}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend entries={simulation sample 1,
                measurement sample 1,
                simulation sample 2,
                measurement sample 2},
legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot[mark=o,color=blue] coordinates {
  (0,0)
  (1,1)
  (2,2)
};
\addplot[mark=o,color=green] coordinates {
  (0,1)
  (1,1.5)
  (2,1.8)
};
\addplot[mark=square,color=blue] coordinates {
  (3,0.5)
  (4.5,1)
  (5,2)
};
\addplot[mark=square,color=green] coordinates {
  (3,0)
  (4,1)
  (5,2.2)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this image:

[image]

But now I want to group my legend entries and only have an entry with line color blue to indicate the simulations and one with line color green for measurements and then one for the circle marker for the sample 1 and one for the square marker to indicate the sample 2. How do I achieve this? Can I insert a ghost plot which is only visible in the entries, or can I use the `\addlegendimage` command to adjust the legend image?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's slightly different version of Martin H's excellent answer that works without the `\addlegendentry` commands and uses the `legend entries` key instead (I find that to be more readable). The `legend entries` are assigned to the `\addplot` and `\addlegendimage` commands in the order they're given, so if you move the `\addlegendimage`s before the `\addplot`s (or if you add `forget plot` to the `\addplot` options), you can use the `legend entries` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend entries={simulation,
                measurement,
                sample 1,
                sample 2},
legend pos=outer north east]
\addlegendimage{no markers,green}
\addlegendimage{no markers,blue}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=o}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=square}
\addplot[mark=o,color=blue] coordinates {
  (0,0)
  (1,1)
  (2,2)
};
\addplot[mark=o,color=green] coordinates {
  (0,1)
  (1,1.5)
  (2,1.8)
};
\addplot[mark=square,color=blue] coordinates {
  (3,0.5)
  (4.5,1)
  (5,2)
};
\addplot[mark=square,color=green] coordinates {
  (3,0)
  (4,1)
  (5,2.2)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to get the first part of your custom legend like so

```
\addlegendimage{line legend,green}
\addlegendentry{Simulation}
\addlegendimage{line legend,blue}
\addlegendentry{Measurement}
```

obviously for that to work you should comment the `legend entries=` that you have in your code now. Just add the above code after you `\addplot` commands.

I am not sure how to get the matching plot marks

**EDIT**

With the comment from Jake this seems to work

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}




\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[forget plot] coordinates {(1,1) (2,2)};
\addlegendimage{line legend,green} % or mark=none?
\addlegendentry{Simulation}
\addlegendimage{line legend,blue}
\addlegendentry{Measurement}
\addlegendimage{green,mark=square}
\addlegendentry{Set 1}
\addlegendimage{blue,mark=o}
\addlegendentry{Set 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can pass the same options to `\addlegendimage` as you would to `\addplot`, so to get the circle and square marks, you could use `\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=o}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=square}`. Also, if you put the `\addlegendimage` commands before your `\addplots`, and/or you add `forget plot` to the `\addplots`, you can still use the `legend entries` key and don't have to use `\addlegendentry`.

Comment: I didn't see that in the manual, must have missed it, but thanks a lot for the clarification!