# Legend image arguments for the command `\addlegendimage`, 3d legend image

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

In the 3d plot

[image]

I want to modify the third legend entry to only show the marks and not the line. From

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113765/28093

I understood that I'm supposed to use something like `\addlegendimage{only marks}` for the third entry. However, since the `\addlegendimage{...}` have to be in order of the plots (without `forget plot`), I still have to know what to use in `\addlegendimage{...}` for the two surfaces. I do not know what arguments I should use to get the nice 3d mesh legend entry. I can't find it in the `pgfplots` manual at the documentation of the command `\addlegendimage{...}`.

Furthermore, only wanting to change to `only marks` and not the color or type of legend entry, with what commands do you retrieve the color and type as used in the `\addplot` command?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xmin=0,xmax=1,xtick={0,1},xlabel=$x$,ymin=0,ymax=1,ytick={0,1},ylabel=$y$,zmin=0,zmax=1,ztick={0,1},legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north west,draw=none,fill=none},legend cell align=left,view={45}{10}
        ]

            % What should I put here?
            %\addlegendimage{???};
            %\addlegendimage{???};
            %\addlegendimage{???};

            % phi
            \addplot3[mesh,blue,domain=0:1,domain y=1/2:1,samples=5] {0};\addlegendentry{plot 1};
            \addplot3[mesh,blue,domain=0:1/2,domain y=0:1/2,samples=5,forget plot] {(x-0)*(y-1/2)/((1/2-0)*(0-1/2))};
            \addplot3[mesh,blue,domain=1/2:1,domain y=0:1/2,samples=5,forget plot] {(x-1)*(y-1/2)/((1/2-1)*(0-1/2))};

            % phi*2*sin(2*pi*x)        
            \addplot3[mesh,red,domain=0:1,domain y=1/2:1,samples=5] {0};\addlegendentry{plot 2};
            \addplot3[mesh,red,domain=0:1/2,domain y=0:1/2,samples=5,forget plot] {(x-0)*(y-1/2)/((1/2-0)*(0-1/2))*0.6*(sin(deg(2*pi*x))+1)};
            \addplot3[mesh,red,domain=1/2:1,domain y=0:1/2,samples=5,forget plot] {(x-1)*(y-1/2)/((1/2-1)*(0-1/2))*0.6*(sin(deg(2*pi*x))+1)};

            \addplot3[draw=none,black,mark=o] coordinates { (0,0,0)
                                                            (1/2,0,0)
                                                            (1,0,0)
                                                            (1,1/2,0)
                                                            (1,1,0)
                                                            (1/2,1,0)
                                                            (0,1,0)
                                                            (0,1/2,0)};\addlegendentry{plot 3};        
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\addplot3[draw=none...`, use `\addplot3[only marks,...`. Then the legend will be shown correctly.

Comment: @Jake Indeed that works! Very pragmatic. Still, I would like to know what the commands are for 

1) surface/mesh legend image entry and 
2) retrieving the `\addplot` color and type, to use it an instance of `\addlegendimage{}`.

Comment: @Jake Would you like to answer?

Comment: @Adriaan, for 1) The definition can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/code/ci/master/tree/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex) starting from line 3263. For 2) When I understand it right, the trick is that `\addlegendimage` is used for *custom* stuff and don't touches the normal `\addplot`s. So the only way to get this data would be to define a custom style which you use for the `\addplot` and for the `addlegendimage` commands.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.